# Precautions while upgrading Jenkins 1.631 to 1.651.3

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Could you please let me know what precautions need to be taken while upgrading Jenkins from 1.631 to 1.651.3 other than config.xml of Jenkins and Jobs along with Plugins.

I have 'n' no# of jobs configuration and how to achieve the roll back.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to check change-log from official site first, as people use different functions / plugins in different way. And you can install the new version in different host, to check your jobs before applying to production env.